# C++ ambiguity in function executor with arguments passed in vector

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I am fighting with this variadic template for a long time. Could anyone help me please? I would like to build an executor that is able to call cmath functions and pass all its parameters through vector. Please consider a following code:

```
bool execute(const std::string &functionName, const std::vector<double> &params)
{
    if (functionName == "cos") return execute(cos, params);
    if (functionName == "atan2") return execute(atan2, params);
    return false;
}
```

Function `cos` takes one parameter while `atan2` takes two. I wanted to have something like this:

```
template <typename... Types>
bool execute(double (*func)(Types...), const std::vector<double> &params)
{
    if (params.size() != sizeof...(Types)) {
        errorString = "Wrong number of function arguments";
        return false;
    }

    errno = 0;
    result = func(params[0]);
    errorString = strerror(errno);
    return !errno;
}
```

However, I encountered two problems:

1. function `cos` works for both `double` and `float`, so call is ambiguous. Moreover, I cannot use `double` in place of `typename` to force it. Or there is other way?
2. When I am trying to call function `func` how can I specify right amount of arguments from vector depending on type of function?

Or maybe there is something already available in C++ which I do not know about? :) Many Thanks!

Comment: Since you apparently only need to handle functions with one and two parameters, it would be easiest to write two non-template overloads, one taking `double(*func)(double)` and the other `double(*func)(double, double)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks. That is what I am actually doing right now. I just wanted to reduce the amount of code with templates. However I do not know if it is anyhow possible.

Comment: It's possible, but I don't think it would actually reduce the amount of code. It would sure make it much more convoluted.

Comment: How about using `std::array` instead of `std::vector`? Then it's quite simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `std::index_sequence`, something like:

```
template <typename... Types, std::size_t ... Is>
double execute(double (*func)(Types...),
               const std::vector<double> &params,
               std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    if (params.size() != sizeof...(Types)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Wrong number of function arguments");
    }
    return func(params[Is]...);
}

template <typename... Types>
double execute(double (*func)(Types...), const std::vector<double> &params)
{
    return execute(func, params, std::index_sequence_for<Types...>());
}
```

And call it (specify template argument to fix overload).

```
double execute(const std::string &functionName, const std::vector<double> &params)
{
    if (functionName == "cos") return (execute<double>)(cos, params);
    if (functionName == "atan2") return (execute<double, double>)(atan2, params);
    throw std::runtime_error("Unknown function name");
}
```